# Why Chart.js's tooltip appears in wrong position when mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, tooltip, chart.js

This is my code with new version of **Chart.js**

```
<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),9000,randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),20000,randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),8977,randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: false,
        showTooltips: true,
         bezierCurve : false,
          pointDot : false,

    });
}


</script>
```

**and the result is..**

[image]

--> the red point is my mouse hover but that wrong! correct position should be black point

thank you :)

Comment: yeah looks like an issue with the way chartjs gets the data at event, reproduced as a fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/gsgLmhu5/ maybe see if there is anything about this on their issues page on github. when there is less data it seems to be fine http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/wxacmcb3/

Answer (score 6):

The default hit detection radius is a bit large. Try setting

```
pointHitDetectionRadius : 1,
```

This provides more definition on a graph with many datapoints.

Update: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsgLmhu5/2/)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with the tooltip being nowhere near my mouse. This will make the tooltip lock to the nearest point to the mouse:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'nearest',
    intersect: false
  }
}
```

This is an example of what it looks like (the red dot is where my mouse is):
[image]

Comment: `mode: 'nearest',` worked, while the answer of wanos did not.

Answer (score 1):

make tooltip like this it works

```js
 tooltips: {
            mode: 'label',
            position: "nearest",
            label: 'mylabel',
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return   data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label+ " "  + number_format2(tooltipItem.yLabel.toString(), 2, ',', '.') ; }, },
        }
```